# Force IE9 Standards mode on one page without modifying masterpage

Tags: 2010

Is there a way that I can force the sharepoint page to use the following metatag:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
```

Without being too invasive and proposing a future maintenance issue. I realize I can create a new master page and just use it for this instance but there must be a better way.

Answer (score -1):

One option is to edit the IIS settings (on each front-end server):

1. Open IIS console
2. Go to Sites and select the Site hosting SharePoint
3. Go to "HTTP Response Headers"
4. Add a header 'X-UA-Compatible' with value 'IE=9'

Comment: This is for one page.